# How do you order objects in an arraylist by one parameter then if that parameter is the same order those by another in java?

Tags: java, object, arraylist

So I have an array list with the class players and an object created from a constructor with the parameters players(points, trophy).

```
ArrayList<players> team = new ArrayList<players>();
players player = new players(15,2);
players player2 = new players(15,5);
players player3 = new players(14,8);
team.add(player);
team.add(player2);
team.add(player3);
```

I would like to sort by the number of points so that the highest points print first then if the number of points is the same sort those with the same number of points by the number of trophies.
I have tried the collections methods like this

```
Collections.sort(team,Comparator.comparingInt(players::getPoints).reversed())
```

This managed to print the right order for points but I was unable to sort by trophies if points were the same.

Comment: What does the `players` class look like? Also, in the future, it is considered bad practice to name your class in all lower case.

Comment: The players class is just one constructor with the variables and some get and set methods .

Comment: The reason I asked is because, as Manashree Shah provided in his answer, it is not obvious by your code that `getTrophies` is a valid method. This is why these sort of details matter.

Comment: Apologies, I'll try to make sure my questions are more detailed in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Collections.sort(team, Comparator.comparingInt(players::getPoints).thenComparingInt(players::getTrophies).reverse());
```

Comment: Managed to get it to work by removing the reversed in the middle but thank you.